# Redshift procedure - Error returning result as cursor

Tags: transactions, amazon-redshift, database-cursor

I am trying to return a cursor from a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_my_test_sp
        (
        rs_out INOUT refcursor
        ) as $$
   
BEGIN
    OPEN rs_out FOR 
    select 'TestValue' Field1; 
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Use cursor within transaction:

```
BEGIN;
CALL sp_my_test_sp('mycursor'); 
FETCH 100 FROM mycursor;
COMMIT;
```

And get the following two errors. I can not understand at what point what error is triggered. In either case, no result is returned.

Error 1:

```
ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block [ErrorId: 1-63efe90b-09bf32ed3f42e3367ce3fd1c]
```

Error 2:

```
ERROR: cursor "mycursor" does not exist [ErrorId: 1-63efe8cf-40c497f3251106b0061d1485]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform a ROLLBACK; before calling.  You have an error in your current session (some previous command) that is blocking subsequent commands from running until the transaction block is closed.

Comment: I tried, but got the same error

Comment: Very odd.  The first error you are getting is due to an aborted transaction which only comes from some other command having an error within the block.  Your code works fine for me so I think the issue is elsewhere.  One thing I would recommend is to COMMIT you SP before use but I don't think this is the source of the error.